# Auto apply Coupon code already logged in customer

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon, coupon-codes

i want to apply coupon code automatically for logged in customer when it comes view cart page .when page loaded it is automatically applied.if user is not logged in than they want to add manually for that one.

Answer (score 0):

use two shopping cart - rules,

1) for connected users select only the usergroup of register users, without code and the promo you like apply.

2) promo with code and assigned only for the group "NOT LOGGED IN" with a code and the promo you like apply.

the two will swicth when the user is connected because change of usergroup, i hope you assing a usergroup to your registered customers

Comment: yes you are right but i want suppose i create coupon like DIXIT15 FOR 15% Off it is automatic display DIXIT15 is applied but when in your case no coupon is display  i want to display this coupon already applied

Comment: that seems some hard to write with a observer, but i thing a easy bypass is create a no value product put a image say Promo and in small description put your msg, and add this product to shopping cart with the promo for connected users, well you can add this product in the two promo to keep the same UX